# ADFS and Form Authentication

Tags: forms, authentication, adfs

I have an ADFS single sign on application. Can we also have form authentication using login credential from a database on the same application? In other words, I need single-sign-on for people who have windows account and form authentication for people who do not have windows account.  I did some research on this topic but I have no lead. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: Did you end up coding this, could you share your solution here please? Did you have to code your own Custom Authentication Provider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the box ADFS can only authenticate against Active Directory (The latest version of ADFS (vNext) do supports [LDAP v3-compliant directories](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn823754.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

You need to build your own Custom Authentication Provider for ADFS if you would like to plugin your custom code.

Some pointers for further reading:

1. [Understanding WIF 4.5](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/504399/Understanding-Windows-Identity-Foundation-WIF)
2. [Create a Custom Authentication Provider for Active Directory Federation Services](http://blogs.technet.com/b/cloudpfe/archive/2014/02/01/how-to-create-a-custom-authentication-provider-for-active-directory-federation-services-3-0-part-1.aspx)